# how to run drupal aggregator outside cron.php?

Tags: drupal, cron, aggregator

i am using aggregator core module in drupal and i need to schedule it in crontab but outside cron.php
i tried **wget http://mywebsite.com/admin/content/aggregator/update/1**
i got 403 forbidden error
i tried curl as well and it returns this as html part

```
  You are not authorized to access this page
```

although i have set the permission of this module to anonymous users!!

any idea is highly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks All for your help!!
i solved my problem by scheduling the following code as a cron and thus it runs aggregator cron as i want:

```
<?php
require_once '/var/www/htdocs/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
module_invoke('aggregator','cron');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this url http://mywebsite.com/admin/config/services/aggregator/update/1 ?

Comment: wget http://mywebsite.com/admin/config/services/aggregator/update/1
==>returns:
Resolving mywebsite.com... xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Connecting to mywebsite.com|xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2011-01-26 12:43:57 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

There are alternatives to the default cron which runs all cron implementations, for example [Elysia Cron](http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron), see [kbahey's blog post about it](http://2bits.com/drupal-performance/improving-performance-drupals-cron-using-elysia-cron-module.html).

At least that's what I assume you want to do, run it more or less often than the other cron implementations.